# ios local notification - get rid of "Notification" text on the lock screen

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, ios13

I am showing local notifications using the following code. It shows fine when the phone is not locked and the app is in background. However when the screen is locked, it shows an additional line with the text `Notification` below the subtitle.

Since my notifications do not have `body`, is there anyway I can get rid of that extra line with the text `Notification`. I tried setting body to `nil` (though xcode gives warning) and also blank string `@""` but neither helped.

```
UNMutableNotificationContent *content = [[UNMutableNotificationContent alloc] init];
content.title = title;
content.subtitle = subtitle;
content.body = nil; // warning, also tried @""
content.categoryIdentifier = category;

    
UNNotificationRequest* request = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:@"LocalNotification" content:content trigger:nil];
    
UNUserNotificationCenter* center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
[center addNotificationRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {

}];
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is the default body placeholder text when the user has set Show Previews to When Unlocked. To change the placeholder text, use a notification category and set its `hiddenPreviewsBodyPlaceholder` parameter.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationcategory/2873733-init

Comment: thank you for reply. I have tried hiddenPreviewsBodyPlaceholder but it only replaces that line with new content but does not remove it. If I pass @"" to the hiddenPreviewsBodyPlaceholder, it shows the default placeholder "Notification".

Comment: Yes, it doesn't want to show no placeholder text at all. You could try a single space instead of an empty string, I suppose, but what you are trying to do is against the system's intentions.

Comment: extra space will still show the empty line. I am not certain about "against the system". I checked WhatsApp notification on the lock screen and it does not show the placeholder at all and hence I think there must be a way.